# Hash partitioning in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am doing a hash partition in Spark using partitionBy() . But the API is not available in RDD class.But it shows not able to resolve partitionBy() .I am running in standalone machine and Spark core version is 1.2 .

```
import org.apache.spark.{HashPartitioner, SparkConf, SparkContext}

val sparkConf=new SparkConf();
sparkConf.setAppName("ReduceTest");
sparkConf.setMaster("local[2]");

val sparkContext=new SparkContext(sparkConf);
val testrdd = sparkContext.parallelize[Int](List(1,2,3,4,6,8,4,5,6));

testrdd.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(100))
```

Comment: Any specific reason to run that older version of `Spark`? There is already `Spark v1.6.1`

Comment: @AvihooMamka I am following "Learning Spark" Book , there it is mentioned the version used in book is 1.2 . Hence i was using . Is it like 1.2 version does not have this API

Comment: Changed to 1.6.0 version . Still same issue  :(

Comment: what build manager are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

`partitionBy` method is defined only on `RDD[(K, V)]` (usually called `PairRDD`) where the first elements is considered to be a key and used for partitioning. So the problem here is not a missing API but your data.

Comment: Thanks!! Issue went off with paired rdd and version 1.6.0 . But I am not sure even though I had taken paired rdd using spark version 1.2 . I was getting same issue .